# Book chapter crossref using hyperlink worked in Bookdown but failed to render in Quarto

Tags: python, r, hyperlink, bookdown, quarto

I have a bookdown project in R which has been rendered successfully. In the book, most of the time I am using conventional hyper link to refer to chapter. For example

In chapter pivoting.Rmd, the title is below without specifying the chapter label (inside the curl bracket

```
# Pivoting data {}
```

Then in chapter cleaning.Rmd, I cross reference the pivoting chapter using conventional hyperlink (without specifying the label)

```
Read more in the chapter [Pivoting data]
```

However, when I port the project to Quarto book, I have to change all .Rmd files to .qmd files, and those chapter links were broken. They are displayed as normal text. I read the [Quarto document](https://quarto.org/docs/books/book-crossrefs.html), if I want to use the conventional hyperlink, either the chapter should have label or specifying the source file like this:

```
[about](about.qmd)
[about](about.qmd#section)
```

My wish is to find the way addressing the problem systematically, because I couldn't add label to chapter and then find hyperlinks to add them manually in order to proper displayed.

Comment: In quarto the links are created by `# Pivoting data {#sec-pivoting_data}` and references by `@sec-pivoting_data`. For details please check https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/cross-references.html

Comment: Hi I am aware about it. My question was I already had chapter reference using old syntax [chapter title], how can I systematically change to algin with quarto format